# (newbie) using .live() click event on ajax loaded content - Variables gets undefined?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of forms with inputs that holds an id(input.hourid) and a submit button. Here's a simplified version:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="4(unique id)" class="hourid">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitbtn">
</form>
<form>...
+++
```

Here's a simplified version of my jquery script:

```
// when the submitbutten is pressed
$(".submitbtn").live("click", function(event){

    // sets x to the value of the submit buttons sibling input.hourid
    var x = $(this).siblings("input.hourid").val();

    alert(x);

    // prevents default submit behavior
    return false 
});
```

So this works great and alerts the value of the clicked elements sibling input.hourid.

BUT, this list of forms is reloaded by ajax at one point(ie. when i submits an insert form) like this:

```
$.get(
    '/newlistprocessor',
    null,
    function(received){
        // prints the reveiced html into #mydiv
        $("#mydiv").html(received);
    }
);
```

And after the div are reloaded with the new forms, all i get from the .live() alert function is "Undefined". Like it's not able to bind the variable x with the selector.

Now why is that?

The reason I'm using the live() function is because I read that the .live function was able to use click events on ajax loaded content(after document.ready). I also read that the on() function is supposed to replace the .live() function as for jquery 1.7. Since I'm using 1.7.x should I then use .on() instead? If so, is there some code out there thats fits my example using .on("click"..) on ajax loaded content?

Comment: What does `received` look like? I imagine that your selector `$(this).siblings("input.hourid")` is not valid for new elements on the page.

Comment: You were absolutely right, Andrew! The ajax received respons had different class names compared to the original html which used another template. An embarrassing mistake, but thank you very much!

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you post one below! If you do, it might probably be a good idea to include that it's better to load the ajax content with ajax in the first place. Instead of having two sets of html, one on regular url-GET and a different one that replaces the content with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Your class selector is wrong.

Change this:

```
var x = $(this).siblings("input.hourid").val();
```

to this:

```
var x = $(this).siblings("input.hours").val();
```

and it should work.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XdqPf/

---

Since you're using jQuery 1.7, you *should* use `on`. Here's how:

Change this:

```
$(".submitbtn").live("click", function(event){
```

to this:

```
$("#mydiv").on("click", ".submitbtn", function(event){
```

This is much more efficient. Read the [jQuery docs on `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XdqPf/1/

Comment: The class selector was simply a typo, sorry about that. Andrew(comment on my first post) got me to take an extra look at the received html from when the ajax content is reloaded, which led me to find out that it used different names(doh). However, the .on() function is working great as you explained, so thank you very much for that snippet!